# NaN value generated for large input while finding standard deviation of numbers with map-reduce?

Tags: java, mapreduce, nan

I used the [code given here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordStandardDeviation.java) and modified it to find standard deviation of numbers. The input is a file containing only numbers, separated by `\n`.
I am generating the input using a C code for random number generator.

Now, when I run the program, it runs fine for 100,000 values, gives a correct output, but when I increase it to 100,000 values, the standard deviation is returned as `NaN`.

I don't understand why it shouldn't be a number, there is no problem in the input file, I have checked already.
Thanks!

Comment: How big are these numbers in the input file?  Could it be possible that numeric overflow is occuring?  Then `Math.sqrt` of a negative number would result in `NaN`.

Comment: It's only random numbers between 1 to 100. I doubt that overflow should be occuring,

Comment: I am slightly confused, the source you linked is for parsing text (words) and not numbers?

Comment: How are you using floating point?  Accumulated floating point errors can definitely result in these sorts of errors.  The "numerically stable algorithm" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm might be noticeably better.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that I modified it to find the Standard deviation of numbers, instead of for words.

Comment: I have used the same algorithm for standard deviation as the link given.

Comment: At what line you getting nan error?